# Prove that is $x\in\mathbb R$ such that there is $\left|1-\sum _{k=1}^{N}a_{k}e^{2\pi ikx}\:\right|\geq1$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

The question is:
Let $a_{1},..,a_{N}\in\mathbb C$ and $k\in\mathbb N$. Prove that there is $x\in\mathbb R$ such that 
$\left|1-\sum _{k=1}^{N}a_{k}e^{2\pi ikx}\:\right|\geq1$

I tried to solve the question using the maximum principle but got stuck in a problem.
Can you help me please?

Answer (score 4):

In fact there must exist such an $x$ in $[0, 1]$. If possible let $|1- \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}a_ke^{2\pi ikx}|<1$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$.  Then $|\int_0^{1} (1- \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}a_ke^{2\pi ikx}) dx| \leq \int_0^{1} |1- \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}a_ke^{2\pi ikx}| dx<\int_0^{1}  1 dx=1$. However $\int_0^{1} (1- \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}a_ke^{2\pi ikx})dx=1-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} 0=1$ so we have a contradiction.

Comment: Can you explain why $\int_0^{2\pi} (1- \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}e^{2\pi ikx})dx=2\pi-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} 0$ ?

Comment: @EladAspis Just integrate all the terms. The integral of $e^{2\pi ikx}$ is $0$ for each $k$.

Comment: I do not think that it affects your argument, but it seems that you omitted the coefficients $a_k$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\int_0^1$ instead of $\int_0^{2 \pi}$, and consequently $x \in [0, 1]$?

Comment: I think it is $\int_0^1$ too

Comment: @EladAspis I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With maximum modulus, just let $P(z)=1-\sum _{n=1}^{N}a_{k}z^k$ the analytic polynomial that coincides with $f$ on the unit circle, $P(e^{2\pi i x})=f(x), x \in \mathbb R$ and of course we can take $x \in [0,1)$ by periodicity

Since $P(0)=1$, maximum modulus implies there is $|z|=1$ hence $x \in \mathbb R$ for which $|f(x)|=|P(e^{2\pi i x})| \ge 1$ and we actually have strict inequality unless all $a_n=0$ Done!